# Does the GWT Compiler reduce unused JavaScript Code of an external Library?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

With GWT I can use JSNI to include external libraries like JQuery.

If I use an external library with JSNI what does the GWT compiler do?

1. Does it include the hole full size JavaScript library?
2. Does it include only the code of the library that have been used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you copied the whole jQuery script into a JSNI method (ouch!), then GWT will do its best to optimize it, including pruning dead code. Results would really depend on the JS code though, not everything can be statically analyzed to determine what code will or won't be used.

Comment: What if you include a js lib with a Script Injector?

Comment: Then you're just loading a script, any script, not necessarily from your own server, and deployed in means that could make it hard if not impossible to know where to find it at compile-time. I.e. GWT can't do anything about it. `ScriptInjector` is no different than putting a `<script>` in your HTML host page, just done dynamically.

Comment: Is there another way of giving GWT the opportunity to reduce the code?

Comment: @stephan1001 aside from writing it in Java, the language that GWT is designed to act on? Or using a JavaScript->JavaScript compiler like Closure? Incidentally, if Closure is enabled in the GWT compile (experimental feature, will add to the build time, may break code that isn't designed for it) it will optimize all JS equally, Java and JSNI alike, but is always turned up to its most aggressive mode.